# PHP Count MySQL value and ignore duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having difficulties counting how many times it finds a new **personnel_id** in table **planning** but ignoring if it finds the same personnel_id a second time.

Exemple **personnel_id 24** is on building A and building B next week but count only as 1 because this is the same person.

In the end I would do something like `$result = $totalpersonnel_id_tablepersonnel - $totalpersonnel_id_tableplanning`and it would give me a number like 7 meaning 7 employees has no building affected.

I think this is the correct query for what I want:

```
$test=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personnel_id) AS numberpid 
FROM planning WHERE personnel_id!='' GROUP BY personnel_id HAVING 
COUNT(personnel_id) > 1");
```

I don't find how to get the sum from this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution :**

`$result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberpid FROM planning WHERE personnel_id!='' GROUP BY personnel_id");
$howmany=mysql_num_rows($result);`

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

if personnel_id!='' mean NOT NULL use personnel_id IS NOT NULL instead and having use numberpid > 1 so query after edited below

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personnel_id) AS numberpid 
FROM planning WHERE personnel_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY personnel_id 
HAVING numberpid > 1
```

Comment: I've now tested your solution and it's returning no result from PhpMyAdmin. I think it's because it's missing a COUNT in HAVING. If I add <code>HAVING count(numberpid) > 1</code> I get a list of numberpid=1. That looks correct but is there a **mysql_result** or something else for it COUNT all those numberpid=1 displayed ? Maybe a <pre>while</pre> to do ? I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use a subquery to filter, group and count by personnel_id, and filter the count in the parrent query.

```
SELECT personnel_id, numberpid 
FROM (
    SELECT count(personnel_id) as numberpid, personnel_id 
    FROM palnning 
    WHERE personnel_id!='' 
    GROUP BY personnel_id) as tmp_table 
WHERE numberpid > 1
```

Comment: That query shows a list of personnel_id who has **numberpid=2**. Is it your method to remove the number of **numberpid=2** found ? Exemple it display 3 numberpid=2 then `$totalpersonnel_id_tableplanning - 3` = correct result ?

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand your question. What the query returns is:personnel_id (id's that you are gtrying to filter),

Comment: Sorry. Hi, not sure I understand your question. What the query returns is: personnel_id (id's that you are gtrying to filter), numberpid (how many entries for that id is found, this is used to filter the one that are greater than 1 as in your initial query). If you want to count how many unique entries you have, change the parent query's `SELECT count(personnel_id) as total_unique` this will give you the total count of unique `personnel_id`'s that are mentioned more than 1 time. (if you want to remove "more than 1 time" filter, simply remove the `WHERE` part of the parent query.